# jQuery search and filter using keywords

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I'm trying to program a search/filter function that searches through unordered list items with data-* attributes based on what the user types in.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()">        
<ul id="myUL">
    <li><a href="#" data-keywords="photography">Digital Media Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-keywords="computers">Information Technology</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-keywords="coding">Programming</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the code I have so far that works only for one data-keywords item. I need help to get it to bring up search results based on multiple keywords.

```
<li><a href="#" data-keywords="photography photoshop illustrator premiere">Digital Media Design</a></li>
```

```
// Search functionality
function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || $(a).data("keywords") === filter.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

If anybody has suggestions on how I can improve the code that would be awesome!

Comment: How many words is the user allowed to type in the box, one or multiple? If it's multiple do they all have to match? If the user searched for `photography media`, would that be expected to match the example node you've given above, with one search term matching the `data-keywords` and the other search term matching the content?

Comment: Also, should searching for `hot` match `photography`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made a few assumptions:

- If multiple search terms are provided they must all match.
- Search terms must be letters, a-z. That could easily be changed to include other characters, such as numbers, but ultimately we need some way to decide where one term ends and the next one begins.
- Matching is based on being a substring.

The bit that needs most explaining is *that* regex. It's using a standard trick for doing an `and` match:

[Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)

So if you search for `digital photography` the RegExp will be equivalent to:

```
/(?=.*digital)(?=.*photography)/i
```

If you wanted searching to be `or` rather than `and` you'd just need to tweak the RegExp accordingly. If you wanted to do a starts-with match rather than substring you could throw in `\b` before each search term (suitably escaped as `\\b` in the string).

I hope the rest is pretty self-explanatory, I tried to stay close to the code in the question.

```js
// Search functionality
function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables
    var input = document.getElementById('myInput'),
        filter = input.value,
        ul = document.getElementById('myUL'),
        lis = ul.getElementsByTagName('li'),
        searchTerms = filter.match(/[a-z]+/gi),
        re, index, li, a;
        
    if (searchTerms) {
        searchTerms = searchTerms.map(function(term) {
            return '(?=.*' + term + ')';
        });
        
        re = new RegExp(searchTerms.join(''), 'i');
    } else {
        re = /./;
    }

    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (index = 0; index < lis.length; index++) {
        li = lis[index];
        a = li.firstChild;

        if (re.test(a.innerHTML + ' ' + a.getAttribute('data-keywords'))) {
            li.style.display = '';
        } else {
            li.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#" data-keywords="photography photoshop illustrator premiere">Digital Media Design</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-keywords="computers">Information Technology</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-keywords="coding">Programming</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
// Get all li's and create an array with each li's data attributes
const lis = document.querySelector("#myUL").children;

const keywordArray = [];

[...lis].forEach((li, i) => {
  keywordArray.push(li.children[0].dataset.keywords);
});

function myFunction() {
  //Show any previous hidden li's
  [...lis].forEach(li => {
    li.style.display = 'block';
  });

  const inputArray = document.querySelector('#myInput').value.split(' ');
  const indexes = [];
  // For each word in the input field, search through our data attribute array
  inputArray.forEach(term => {
    keywordArray.forEach((keywords, i) => {
      keywords.split(' ').forEach(keyword => {
        // If we find a match, add the index of the data attribute array, which
        // will be the same as the index of the li element
        if (keyword === term) {
          indexes.push(i);
        }
      });
    });
  });
  // If we have a match, hide every non-matching li'
  if (indexes.length) {
    [...lis].forEach((li, i) => {
      if (!indexes.includes(i)) {
        li.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
  }
}
```

For clarification, do you want additional search terms to make the search more specific or less specific? Because my solution makes the search less specific as it will show any li matching any search term.