# How to combine two regex using AND operator

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a dilemma in using regex as I am very new in using this:

I have the URL below:

```
var url = https://website.com/something-here/page.html?p=null#confirmation?order=123
```

My expected result is:

```
/something-here/page.html #confirmation
```

It could be a space or a comma or simply combine the two(/something-here/page.html#confirmation)

I can do this using two regex below:

```
var a= url.match(/som([^#]+).html/)[0];

var b= url.match(/#([^#]+).tion/)[0];

console.log(a,b);
```

But I would like to have it done as a single regex with the same result.

Comment: Why a single regExp, if two regExps do what you need?

Comment: 1. What is the purpose of your regex your final aim; the use. 
2. What is that space for?

Comment: I would like to try to combine them or at least create a single regEx as a single field on a form I'm trying to create *should* only accept one-liner regex. :(

I tried this format ^(?=.*some)(?=.*#) but it doesn't work.

The space is just to separate the two but its not really a factor. I mean, they can be together with a comma or be combined as a one word.

Comment: @LeaSanchez OK, see my update on the post. You have a *one-liner* regexp there.

Comment: Hi @Bekim Bacaj, your suggestion works properly. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: What about [`^https?:\/{2}[^\/]*(\/[^?]*)[^#]*(#[^?]*).*$` replace with `$1 $2`](https://regex101.com/r/A7c7UA/1)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegExp's group system to your advantage. Here's a snippet:

```
var matches = url.match(/(som[^#]+.html).*?(#[^#]+.tion)/);
console.log(matches[1] + " " + matches[2]); // prints /something-here/page.html #confirmation
```

I combined your two RegExp conditions into one, while enclosing them with parenthesis in the correct areas to create two groups.

That way, you can get the specified group and add a space in between.

Comment: Hello @Tals, I tried to run it but it gives me an unexpected error due to the array for matches. When I remove them, it gives me a null value.

I have also tried to replace the value with [0] and [1] respectively but still the same unexpected error still occurs.

Thanks for this suggestion as well. :)

Comment: Hi Tals,
its a mistake on my end, I'm running it on the other sheet that I'm using for test haha. My apologies. This is correct and running.

Comment: Cool! Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Aside the fact that your example url is malformed (you have two search params), therefore not very suitable to work with -  I have e proposition:

**Why not use the URL object and its properties?**

```
url = new URL("https://website.com/something-here/page.html?p=null#confirmation?order=123");
```

and precisely grab the properties with explicit syntax as in:

`url.pathname;` *>> "something-here/page.html"*

`url.hash;` *>> "#confirmation?order=123"*

***But in case you explicitly need a RegExp variant***

here is one

```js
var url = "https://website.com/something-here/page.html?p=null#confirmation?order=123";
var match =  url.match(/\/som.*?html|\#.*?tion/g);

console.log(match.join(" "));
```

Comment: Hi Bekim, tahnk you so much for this. I was able to run it and it now works. Thank you so much for your help! ^_^

Comment: @LeaSanchez Great, (now you should mark the thread as solved, e.g. accept the answer that works best for you ). :)

Answer (score -1):

Use each your condition in scope "( )" More details answer try find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)