# Regex if contain word 'ABC' select and if contain 'EFG' dont select even if it contains 'ABC'

Tags: java, regex

Need Regex for

*Abc your request is Approved.*

In above statement if word 'Approved' comes in sentence it should select whole sentence.

*Mr. Abc your request is Approved.*

and if word 'Mr' comes in sentence it should not select a sentence even though it contains 'Approved' word.

Comment: Please try [here](https://regexr.com/).

Comment: what's keeping you from writing it?

Comment: @vinS I am trying on same [link](https://regexr.com)  . I dont know regex much, put regex pattern .

Comment: Please invest some time in learning. Putting a requirement straight away as a question will lead to nothing. As you have seen, your question is already downvoted. BTW, I have not downvoted. Better to try with something and edit your question in order to show your effort.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator/44781456#44781456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

`^(?!Mr).*(Approved).*`

It will select those lines which **doesn't** start with `Mr`, but **have** the word `Approved` inside (it can or not be at the end )

Working example [here](https://regex101.com/r/hr0r8k/1)

Comment: What if "Mr." comes after "Approved"?

Comment: Thats true!, i will check

Comment: You may check my answer. If anything is missing, notify me.

Comment: I think that won't check neither if `Mr` appears after `Approved` [Take a look](https://regex101.com/r/hr0r8k/4)

Comment: Huh? It checks as it seen. OP says if "Mr." appears in sentence, don't match it. In this link, the expected result is shown.

Comment: Yeah yeah, completely true, i said nothing XD

Answer (score 2):

`((?!Mr).)*` matches string that doesn't contain `"Mr."`. If you check it before and after of the word `"Approved"`, you're done.

```
^((?!Mr.).)*Approved((?!Mr.).)*$
```

Example:

```
Abc your request is Approved. -> Match
Mr. Abc your request is Approved. -> No match
Abc your request is Approved. Mr. -> No match
Abc your Mr. request is Approved. -> No match
```

Comment: So what's the problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this regex can help you [`^(?i)((?=\bApproved\b).)*((?!\bMr\b).)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/2lYKAZ/1)

```
String approved = "Abc your request is Approved.";
String notApproved = "Mr. Abc your request is Approved.";
String regex = "(?i)((?=\\bApproved\\b).)*((?!\\bMr\\b).)*";
```

If you use :

```
System.out.println(approved.matches(regex));
System.out.println(notApproved.matches(regex));
```

Outputs

```
true
false
```