# Search filter regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, search, notepad++

Is anyone able to tell me what regex I should use to search with 2 conditional arguments within Notepad++.

if i have a line in a log that reads:
"Packet     : NTFY 11279 Int#0/5 MGCP 1.0"

and I want to search for all lines that contain "NTFY" and "Int#0/5" and ignore all other lines, what would the syntax of the regex be?

I know that "NTFY | Int#0/5" will search for lines with NTFY or Int#0/5 but that would not filter enough.

thanks.

Comment: `(?=.*NTFY)(?=.*Int#0/5)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)

Answer (score 0):

The info provided by ctwheels in the question comment is reasonable but I don't think it takes it far enough for Notepad++ and here's why:

While:

```
(?=.*NTFY)(?=.*Int#0/5)
```

matches the desired lines, it zero-length-matches at EVERY POSITION from the start of a line containing the search terms to the start of either search term on that line.  Thus if your line looks like this:

```
zzzInt#0/5zNTFY
```

you will obtain 4 matches on that line instead of 1.

Changing the search expression slightly, to:

```
^(?=.*NTFY)(?=.*Int#0/5)
```

solves that problem and provides one hit per matching line.