# Regex / Pattern HTML email

Tags: html, regex

Is there a way to associate two regex ?

I have this one which prevents user to use this email (test@test.com)

> pattern="^((?!test@test.com).)*$"

I also have one which validates email syntax

> pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]{3,}@[a-z]{3,}([.]{1}[a-z]{2,}|[.]{1}[a-z]{2,}[.]{1}[a-z]{2,})"

How to merge those two regex in order to prevent user to user test@test.com and to validate the email syntax ?

I tried to use an OR operator (single pipe) but I am missing something, it doesn't work ...

Thanks !

Comment: It would be much easier to validate email (e.g. via regex), and then just separately check that the email isn't "test@test.com" via plain string comparison.

Comment: Probably you want `pattern="(?!test@test.com$)[\w.%+-]{3,}@[a-z]{3,}\.[a-z]{2,}(?:\.[a-z]{2,})?"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works ! Could you please explain in an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may use

```
pattern="(?!test@test\.com$)[a-z0-9._%+-]{3,}@[a-z]{3,}\.[a-z]{2,}(?:\.[a-z]{2,})?"
```

Note that the HTML5 patterns are automatically anchored as they are wrapped with `^(?:` and `)$` at the start/end, so no need adding `^` and `$` at the start/end of the pattern.

The `(?!test@test\.com$)` negative lookahead will fail the match if the input string is equal to the `test@test.com` string (unlike your first regex that only fails the input that contains the email).

The rest is your second pattern, I only removed `{1}` that are implicit and contracted an alternation group to a `\.[a-z]{2,}(?:\.[a-z]{2,})?` where `(?:\.[a-z]{2,})?` is an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 sequences of `.` and 2 or more lowercase ASCII letters.

Add `A-Z` to the character classes to also support uppercase ASCII letters.

Comment: If I need this pattern to be supported by IE 11, do I need to add ^ and $ ?

Comment: @Defoncesko HTML5 adds `^` and `$` at the start/end automatically. This pattern will work the same in all browsers.