# Regex that excludes spaces and requires 2 capital letters or more

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression that matches strings with:

- 19 to 90 characters
- symbols
- at least 2 uppercase alphabetical characters
- lowercase alphabetical characters
- no spaces

I already know that for the size and space exclusion the regex would be:

```
^[^ ]{19,90}$
```

And I know that this one will match any a string with at least 2 uppercase characters:

```
^(.*?[A-Z]){2,}.*$
```

What I don't know is how to combine them. There is no context for the strings.

Edit: I forgot to say that it is better ifthe regex excludes strings that finish with a .com or .jpeg or .png or any .something (that "something" being of 2-5 characters).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)

Comment: What symbols do you allow?

Comment: @wp78de any symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [regex](https://regex101.com/r/6Z481l/2) should do what you want.

```
^(?=(?:\w*\W+)+\w*$)(?=(?:\S*?[A-Z]){2,}\S*?$)(?=(?:\S*?[a-z])+\S*?$)(?!.*?\.\w{2,5}$).{19,90}$
```

Basically it uses three positive lookaheads and a negative lookahead to guarantee the conditions that you specified:

```
(?=(?:\w*\W+)+\w*$)
```

ensures that there is at least one non-word (symbol) character

```
(?=(?:\S*?[A-Z]){2,}\S*?$)
```

ensures that there are at least two uppercase characters, and also excludes a match if there are any spaces in the string

```
(?=(?:\S*?[a-z])+\S*?$)
```

ensures that there is at least one lowercase character in the string. The negative lookahead

```
(?!.*?\.\w{2,5}$)
```

ensures that strings that end with a . and 2-5 characters are excluded

Finally,

```
.{19.90}
```

performs the actual match and ensures that there are between 19 and 90 characters.

Comment: Thanks. That was more complicated that I though. Just that I needed to exclude the strings with `.*?\.\w{2,5}` at the end. I this case it is a requirement.

Comment: Your question says you want to exclude strings that **don't** finish with that pattern...

Answer (score 1):

Following your requrements, I suggest to use the following pattern:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*[^\s]).{19,90}$
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/DaqfnB/1)

Instead of just excluding spaces, I used `\s`since you probably don't want allow tabs, newlines, etc. either. However, it is still unclear which symbols you want to allow, e.g. `[a-zA-Z!"§$%&\/()=?+]`

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*[^\s])(?=[a-zA-Z!"§$%&\/()=?+]).{19,90}$
```

---

To match your additional requirement not to match file-like extensions at the end of the string, add a negative look-ahead: `(?!.*\.\w{2,5}$)`

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*[^\s])(?=[a-zA-Z!"§$%&\/()=?+]).{19,90}$
```

[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/DaqfnB/2)

Answer (score -1):

You can use backreferences as described here: https://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/and-in-regex/

Another reference with examples here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html