# And operator in REGEX

Tags: regex

I am trying to find two separate groups of text within a document using REGEX in an application.  Example:

```
(facility services|MAFS|MFA|facility|facilities)
(agreement|lease)
```

I only want to identify documents that have a match to one word in both sets of text, such as `facility` and `agreement`.  How would I write that in REGEX?

Comment: `((facility services|MAFS|MFA|facility|facilities)(agreement|lease))`

Comment: `facility|agreement` seems the logical choice. What is `both sets of text` ?

Comment: Currently it's hard to get your intentions. Please provide an example.

Comment: I need to find document that have at least one of the words ((facility services|MAFS|MFA|facility|facilities) AND at least one of the words in (agreement|lease)

Comment: Can they be in either order?

Comment: What language or tool are you using the regexp with?

Comment: There's no need for both `facility` and `facility services`. If it matches `facility services`, it also matches `facility` by itself.

Comment: Active Navigation

Comment: Never heard of that, is it http://activenavigation.com/? What language do you program in when you use it?

Comment: They can be in any order, Active Navigation is a file analysis software, that has a UI to write regex to find groups of words within a document in order to identify document type

Comment: I used this expression: (facility services|MAFS|MFA|facility|facilities)
(agreement|lease) and it found zero results.  However this is a line of text within the document:  FACILITIES EXPANSION AND RISK SHARING AGREEMENT

Comment: The need for a matching both sets of text is to eliminate documents that aren't agreements or leases

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for two matches, just search for both of them in either order using alternation.

```
((MAFS|MFA|facility|facilities)[\s\S]*(agreement|lease))|((agreement|lease)[\s\S]*(MAFS|MFA|facility|facilities))
```

If there are more patterns this doesn't scale well because of combinatorial explosion, so lookaheads are the solution. See [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator/470602#470602)

Answer (score 0):

*This is commonly known as Out-Of-Order matching.*

If you get into a situation where you have more than 2 sets, then the only
efficient way to do it is with an engine that does conditional constructs.

But, this is it for your 2 sets `(?:.*?\b(?:(?(1)(?!))(facility|MAFS|MFA|facilities)|(?(2)(?!))(agreement|lease))\b){2}`

Readable version

```
 (?:
      .*? 
      \b          
      (?:
           (?(1)
                (?!)
           )
           (                        # (1 start)
                facility
             |  MAFS
             |  MFA
             |  facilities
           )                        # (1 end)
        |  
           (?(2)
                (?!)
           )
           ( agreement | lease )    # (2)
      )
      \b 
 ){2}
```