# Using grep to pull multiple headers

Tags: grep

I am trying to return text between header tags `<h1> and </h1>` and also between `<h3> and </h3>`  tags from a text file .  The file has only one `<h1>` and has 4 `<h3>` tags, I'm really only interested in the first 2 `<h3>` tags.  But I want the text between them.

These grep commands produce the correct output one at a time, but when I try and combine them I have problems.

```
grep  -o -P '(?<=<h1>).*(?=</h1>)' file.txt  
grep  -o -P '(?<=<h3>).*(?=</h3>)' file.txt
```

I tried
    `grep  -e '(?<=<h1>).*(?=</h1>)'-e'(?<=<h3>).*(?=</h3>)'`

`grep -o  '(?<=<h1>).*(?=</h1>)'\'(?<=<h3>).*(?=<h3>)'`

I'm not sure what the -P does other than the man page says Perl expression.  But it only allows one -P at a time.  Is there another command that I could use to pull text between

Comment: suggestions: 1) please click [edit] to add a sample input text and expected output for that, it will help to add clarity and in testing before adding answers 2) using regex to parse html/xml is not a good idea, use tools like xmlstarlet instead

Comment: [Don't Parse HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)