# Finding strings that are a certain length and contain specific characters

Tags: r, string, grepl

Sample data

```
a<-c("hour","four","ruoh", "six", "high", "our")
```

I want to find all strings that contain o & u & h & are 4 characters but the order does not matter.

I want to return `"hour","four","ruoh"`
this is my attempt

```
grepl("o+u+r", a) nchar(a)==4
```

Comment: What about testing each separately. You first test (with grep) which elements of the vector contains "o", those who pass, you test if they has "u" and those who pass you test for "h".

Comment: @Cris is this the most simple approach to do so?

Comment: "four" does not contain o & u & h.

Comment: @neilfws I have now done a modification

Comment: @bvowe i'm seeing right now that my solution won't work...

Comment: @bvowe it still says you want to return "four", and that you want strings with o & u & h. I think you mean o & u & r, as in the `grepl`.

Comment: See [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator); `grepl("(?=.*h)(?=.*o)(?=.*u)", a, perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using grepl with your edited method (r instead of h):

```
a<-c("hour","four","ruoh", "six", "high", "our")

a[grepl(pattern="o", x=a) & grepl(pattern="u", x=a) & grepl(pattern="r", x=a) & nchar(a)==4]
```

Returns:

```
[1] "hour" "four" "ruoh"
```

Answer (score 2):

To match strings of **length 4** containing the characters **h**, **o**, and **u** use:

```
grepl("(?=^.{4}$)(?=.*h)(?=.*o)(?=.*u)",
      c("hour","four","ruoh", "six", "high", "our"),
      perl = TRUE)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

- `(?=^.{4}$)`: string has length 4.
- `(?=.*x)`: `x` occurs at any position in string.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `strsplit` and `setdiff`, I added an additional edge case to your sample data :

```
a<-c("hour","four","ruoh", "six", "high", "our","oouh")
a[nchar(a) == 4 &
  lengths(lapply(strsplit(a,""),function(x) setdiff(x, c("o","u","h")))) == 1]
# [1] "hour" "ruoh"
```

or `grepl` :

```
a[nchar(a) == 4 & !rowSums(sapply(c("o","u","h"), Negate(grepl), a))]
# [1] "hour" "ruoh" "oouh"
```

`sapply(c("o","u","h"), Negate(grepl), a)` gives you a matrix of which word doesn't contain each letter, then the `rowSums` acts like `any` applied by row, as it will be coerced to logical.

Comment: This might have to be tweaked depending on how you want to treat some edge cases (multiple "h" for example)

Comment: thanks a bunch @Moody_Mudskipper do you have grepl solution?