# Regex AND operator in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

You can use the pipe `|` to represent `OR` and it works fine in Google Sheets. But I want an `AND` operator and can't find that anywhere. [The closest post I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator) was talking about java application but it doesn't run properly on Google Sheets

I want to check if in the string "equivalencia de estudo patrimonial" the strings "equivalencia" and "patrimonial" are present.

I've already tried:

```
=regexmatch("equivalencia de estudo patrimonial";"(?:equivalencia)(?:patrimonial)")
=regexmatch("equivalencia de estudo patrimonial";"(?=equivalencia)(?=patrimonial)")
=regexmatch("equivalencia de estudo patrimonial";"/(equivalencia)(patrimonial)/")
=regexmatch("equivalencia de estudo patrimonial";"(equivalencia)(patrimonial)")
```

No one worked. Always getting false.

Can someone help here?

Comment: `=regexmatch("equivalencia de estudo patrimonial";"equivalencia.*patrimonial|patrimonial.*equivalencia")`?

Comment: great it works!! \o/ there isn't a simpler way to do it like the pipe for OR right?

Comment: Something like `=AND(regexmatch(A1;"\bequivalencia\b"); regexmatch(A1; "\bpatrimonial\b"))` maybe? I added word boundary `\b` to add sense to the `regexmatch` function here.

Comment: good functional solutions. if you'd like to post it, the answer is yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, RE2 library that powers Google Sheets does not support lookarounds.

What you may do is match a combination of `word1.*word2` or `word2.*word1` with a regex like

```
=REGEXMATCH("equivalencia de estudo patrimonial"; "equivalencia.*patrimonial|patrimonial.*equivalencia")
```

Here, `equivalencia.*patrimonial|patrimonial.*equivalencia` matches `equivalencia`, some 0+ chars, `patrimonial`, or (`|`) `patrimonial.*equivalencia` matches `patrimonial`, then any 0+ chars and then `equivalencia`. It is not that efficient due to the `.*` part between the two words.

Another solution is to use the [`AND` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301?hl=en) and run `REGEXMATCH` twice:

```
=AND(REGEXMATCH(A1;"equivalencia"); REGEXMATCH(A1; "patrimonial"))
```