# Using AND in Regex Python

Tags: python, regex

If I am given a sample string like the one given below and I want to extract ids and code values

`demo = '{"orders":[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5},{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8},{"id":9}],"errors":[{"code":3,"message":"[PHP Warning #2] count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (153)"}]}'`

using regex

`r'"id":([0-9]+)'` gets me the ids i.e 1,2,3,4 etc but I am having trouble getting the value inside the key `code` in one regex expression.

I searched for AND operators and stumbled upon

[Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)

but this approach doesn't help me.

Comment: The question you linked to has 12 answers. Can you explain more clearly why none of them would be the answer to your question?

Comment: WHy would you do this with a regexp? Use a JSON parser and extract what you want from the resulting object.

Comment: @IMSoP The answers to the linked question does pattern matching to a string  like "Start with a good word and end with a kind deed" and "Start with a kind word and end with a good deed". In my case I want to extract values of two different keys in a single regex expression .

Comment: @Barmar I know that JSON parser is a better way to go was just curious as to how can this be applied using a Regex Format

Comment: It's the same as the way you get the id: `r'"code":([0-9]+)'`

Comment: What does the AND operator have to do with this?

Comment: @Barmar I want to get the values inside the ids AND code together.

Comment: Be aware that's an OR, not an AND

Comment: @martinspielmann This OR operator gives me the keys and the values as a set i.e ('id' : '1') but what I really want is a single regex expression to get the values i.e 1,2,3,4,5, etc

Answer (score 3):

Use the `|` operator to match alternatives:

```
result = re.findall(r'"(id|code)":([0-9]+)', demo)
print(result)
# prints
[('id', '1'), ('id', '2'), ('id', '3'), ('id', '4'), ('id', '5'), ('id', '6'), ('id', '7'), ('id', '8'), ('id', '9'), ('code', '3')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ast.literal_eval()` instead as your "string" is indeed structured information:

```
from ast import literal_eval

demo = '{"orders":[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5},{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8},{"id":9}],"errors":[{"code":3,"message":"[PHP Warning #2] count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (153)"}]}'

demo = literal_eval(demo)

result = {key: [dct.get(key) for dct in demo[needle]]
          for key, needle in [('id', 'orders'), ('code', 'errors')]}
print(result)
```

This yields

```
{'code': [3], 'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
```