# JavaScript regex for email address with a 40 character limit

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a regex for an email address with the following conditions.

- String must not contain more than 40 characters.
- String matches the format emailid@domain where both emailid and domain contains only lowercase English letters, digits, and period(.)
- domain should contain at least one period(.)
- both email id and domain must not contain any consecutive period (.)

So Far, I am able to fulfill only the second condition with this regex:

```
/^[a-z0-9.]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/
```

Any idea, how can I complete the other conditions?

Comment: You should test email length before doing regex matching, imho.

Comment: You could try `^(?!.{41}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:\.[a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$`

Comment: So `emailid` and `domain` can begin or end with a period?

Comment: Nice one, @Thefourthbird

Comment: @Thefourthbird I have already upvoted your comment which solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single negative lookahead to make sure that the string does not contain 41 characters.

If you repeat the character class without a period 1 or more times,  followed by optionally repeating a group that starts with a period, you prevent matching consecutive periods.

This part `\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$` already makes sure that there is at least a single period.

```
^(?!.{41})[a-z0-9]+(?:\.[a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kwuTlW/1)

Note that because the `-` is still in this character class `[a-z0-9-]+`, consecutive hyphens are still possible. If you don't want to allow this, you can use

```
^(?!.{41})[a-z0-9]+(?:\.[a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(?:[.-][a-z0-9-]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use positive lookahead:

```
/(?=^[a-z0-9.]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$)(?=^.{1,40}$)/
```

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/469951/1031191
by Jason Cohen:

> `"(?=match this expression)(?=match this too)(?=oh, and this)"`

tested on: https://regex101.com/