# Regexp AND (for searching code in intelliJ)

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

i'm trying to find code in IntelliJ with regular expression search , to be able to have AND condition.
i read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator) answer about the matter , but could not make it work
i have this expression

`^(?=.*platform) (?=.*SpringTestBase).*$`
i have tried adding multiline `/m` at the end with no luck.

My Search string would be something like this

```
@MyAnnotation (profile=platform)
class SpringTestBase extends object {
 }
```

Comment: You need the dotall modifier so that `.` captures newlines  or just use `[\s\S]*` instead of `.*`

Comment: Remove the space between the lookaheads as well

Comment: if i try this one i get only 1 match `(?=[\s\S]*platform) (?=[\s\S]*SpringTestBase)`

Comment: The space between the lookaheads is causing an issue. See https://regex101.com/r/HBHaT4/1

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - i think its working with `(?=[\s\S]*platform)(?=[\s\S]*SpringTestBase)[\s\S]*` but in intelliJ this expression search takes foreever :-)

Comment: This could be faster https://regex101.com/r/28RZKF/1 depending on your goal

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  it is working - but in intelliJ does not return any results.

Comment: I don't have intelliJ so you'll have to keep messing with it until it works as expected.

Comment: Note that `extends Object` is redundant. Every class implicitly is a subclass of `java.lang.Object`.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using [Structural Search and Replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html) functionality of IntelliJ, in Edit>Find>Search Structurally…:

```
@MyAnnotation(profile="platform")
class SpringTestBase {
}
```

This will automatically take care of whitespace normalization, different newline style, inheritance, etc. for you.