# How to attach multiple class method from loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

`.regularExpression()` is hardcoded 3 times in the script, is there a way to dynamically attach it from loops from variable `const regex = ['reg1', 'reg2', 'reg3']`?

Usage:

```
{
       text: Check.string()
                  .regularExpression(/reg1/)
                  .regularExpression(/reg2/)
                  .regularExpression(/reg3/)
}
```

Comment: [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913)

Comment: @adiga No, I want to keep it separate. It needs to loop from variable.

Comment: You need to create a regex as mentioned in the linked ticket Something like: `(?=.*reg1)(?=.*reg2)(?=.*reg3)`. So, `const final = ['reg1', 'reg2', 'reg3'].map(str => \`(?=.*${str})\`).join('')` and then `.regularExpression(new RegExp(final ))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `reduce` method:

```
const regex = ['reg1', 'reg2', 'reg3'];
{
  text: regex.reduce((check, regex) => check.regularExpression(new RegExp(regex)), Check.string())
}
```

In this way, starting from the initial value `Check.string()`, you will iteratively chain new regular expressions, accordingly to your array.

Alternatively, you can use a plain for-loop:

```
let check = Check.string();
for (const item of regex) {
  check = check.regularExpression(new RegExp(regex));
}

{
  text: check
}
```

Comment: `regularExpression` only allow 1 param. Eg: `.regularExpression(regex)`

Comment: It's receiving only one parameter, and it is `new RegExp(regex)`