# How do I use RegEx to find parens that contain BOTH numbers and letters, not just one or the other

Tags: javascript, regex

In this example...

```
(5) (dogs)  (5 dogs)  (dogs 5)
```

I would like to only match to...

```
(5 dogs)  -or-  (dogs 5)
```

The numbers could be any number of digits, contain commas, decimal points, math operators, dollar signs, etc. The only thing I need to pay attention to is that there are both numbers and alpha characters present.

I started with this modification of an [example provided by hrs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65002605/199374) using this for the RegEx...

```
\(((letter).*(number))\)|((number).*(letter))\)
```

to only capture this...

```
(number letter)  -or-  (letter number)
```

but not...

```
(number) (letter)
```

by modifying the expression to be...

```
\(((^[a-zA-Z]).*(^[0-9]))\)|((^[0-9]).*(^[a-zA-Z]))\)
```

...but obviously I don't know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative with a single lookahead:

```
\((?=[^)a-z]*[a-z])[^\d)]*\d[^)]*\)
```

**Explanation**

- `\(` Match `(`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `[^)a-z]*[a-z]` Match any char except `)` or a-z, then match a-z
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `[^\d)]*\d` Match any char except a digit or `)` and then match a digit
- `[^)]*` Match any char except `)`
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PHCqwr/1)

```js
const s = '(5) (dogs)  (5 dogs)  (dogs 5)';
const regex = /\((?=[^)a-z]*[a-z])[^\d)]*\d[^)]*\)/ig;

console.log(s.match(regex));
```

Comment: I was about to say that it seemed that the lookahead could just use `[^)]` rather than `[^)a-z]` when I noticed that was what you had done in the regex demo. You might want to update the answer. I guess the same applies to the `[^\d)]*`? What's interesting though is that keeping the `a-z` and `\d` in those character classes actually makes the regex more efficient (if you count steps on PCRE), I guess because it helps it discard non-matches more rapidly.

Comment: @Nick Using the `a-z` and `\d` in the negated character class gets to a match faster using [contrast](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast)

Comment: Thanks for the link - it makes perfect sense. I've updated the regex in my answer to also take advantage of it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use forward lookaheads to assert that there are both a number and a letter within each set of parentheses:

```
\((?=[^)\d]*\d)(?=[^)a-z]*[a-z])[^)]+\)
```

The two lookaheads assert that there are some number of non-closing parenthesis characters and then a digit (first lookahead `(?=[^)\d]*\d)`) or a letter (second lookahead `(?=[^)a-z]*[a-z])`). The `[^)]+` then matches the characters between the `(` and `)`.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gZfLYc/1)

In Javascript:

```js
const str = '(5) (dogs)  (5 dogs)  (dogs 5)'
const regex = /\((?=[^)\d]*\d)(?=[^)a-z]*[a-z])[^)]+\)/ig

console.log(str.match(regex))
```