# Writing a regex that adds a span to each word outside of $ delimiters and html tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use regex to do the following:

1. The regex ignores every inside of html tags
2. The regex ignores everything inside of `$...$` which is parsed by Mathjax
3. The regex ignores everything inside of `$$...$$` which is parsed by Mathjax
4. The regex replaces every word with that word
5. Is accomplished with `<.*?>(.*?)<.*?>`
6. Is accomplished with the opposite of `\$(.*?)\$`)
7. Is accomplished with the opposite of `\$\$(.*?)\$\$`
8. Is accomplished with `replace(/[A-Za-z0-9.]+,"<span class='invisible'>$1</span>")`

I am struggling with combining these 4 since there is no "and" and "not" operators.

There is an explanation of "not" here:
[Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

There is an explanation of "and" here:
[Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)

I tried
`(?=([A-Za-z0-9.]+))(?=<.*?>(.*?)<.*?>)` for and but it didn't work and I wasn't sure how to apply the "not" to items 2 and 3.

Comment: What word do you want to replace your text with? What exactly can your text contain so we can trait it properly? Please upload an example of your text with the desirable results.

Answer (score -1):

This problem may not be well suited to a regular expression. If you do manage to get it working, it will likely be complicated and quite difficult for someone to read and understand the regular expression in the future.

Also, using regular expressions to work through relatively complicated syntax makes it easy to miss edge cases.

For example, your initial approaches may miss things like this:

```
<body>
  <p>Let's all do a thing.</p>
  $something$
  <p>All of us who are < 4 feet tall or > 6 feet tall should.</p>
</body>
```

Instead you could consider using an HTML parsing library, then use a MathJax parsing library on the content of each HTML node. Then wrap a span around each thing that is not handled by MathJax.

Comment: Your example is not valid html (contains `<` and `>`). But your conclusion is ok.